# Complete Mechanism for Oxidation of an Alkene to a Glycol

Tags: organic-chemistry

My organic book does not write out the full mechanism for the reaction of an alkene with osmium tetroxide in a basic aqueous solution with sodium bisulfate. I have made an attempt at a mechanism and am looking for a confirmation or a correction to it. Thanks and I appreciate the help.

I am concerned because the mechanism I wrote creates hydrogen gas and I have not done the reaction so I don't know if a gas evolves. [image]

Comment: We generally don't write detailed arrow pushing mechanisms for the details that occur on a transition metal because arrow pushing mechanisms can fail to describe what is going on.

Comment: In other words, don't try to do too much with the osmium. Focus on what happens to the organic component instead.

Comment: I agree with @Zhe. Whatever happens to the osmium compound doesnt matter, we are concerned with the organic molecules.